# Unable to use SetTransform in D3D9

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d9

What might stop IDirect3DDevice9::SetTransform from working? I've looked at alot of tutorials for using transformation matrices in Direct3D9, including [this one here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/C++/Series1/tut8.php). And as far as I can tell, they all do it the same way.

I'm trying to write some code just to translate a texured polygon. I call SetTransform with a matrix initialized with D3DXMatrixTranslation, and it returns S_OK. However the actual polygons drawn to the screen do not get transformed.

```
D3DXMATRIX m_Translation;
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&m_Translation,100,100,0);
d3dDevice->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &m_Translation);

d3dDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_TLVERTEX);
d3dDevice->SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(TLVERTEX));

HRESULT hr = d3dDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLEFAN, 0, 2);
```

Comment: @GMan: nope. Nothing but two polys and a single texture

Comment: And that's the actual code, nothing in between? I assume you have your other matrices set up as well? (The projection & view)

Comment: I've never heard of this not working in the fixed function pipeline. I recommend you run it through PIX and see what is happening. (also, have you set up the view and projection matrices appropriately?). Though, IMHO, I believe the fixed function pipeline is dead, it hasn't been updated in almost a decade (by either MS or hardware manufacturers) and its usually quicker and easier to develop with shaders because you know exactly what is happening and don't need to deal with this sort of thing (though of course you need to understand what is happening).

Comment: This is just for 2D rendering so my understanding was that the projection matrix etc were not needed, but I'll give that a try and see what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set "D3DFVF_TLVERTEX" which means that you are supplying "Transform and Lit" vertices in the vertex buffer, therefore the device is not going to apply a transformation matrix to these vertices.

Comment: Yes that was it, apparently Transformed also means "and unable to be transformed furthur".